# A British equivalent of saying "tell it to the marines"

Tags: idioms, synonyms

is there a British saying similar in meaning to American "tell it to the marines"?
Thanks.

source- Cambridge dictionary: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell-that-it-to-the-marines

Comment: According to http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/tell-it-to-the-marines.html, "This isn't an American phrase though ..."

Comment: I've been speaking AmE my whole life and have never once heard it.

Comment: Could you add the meaning as you understand it?

Comment: *Pull the other one, it's got bells on*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the source link, once corrected, specifically points out that this *is* British English.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Add an "S" on the end.

Comment: I've never heard that specific saying, but "Tell that to X" is used the same way, where X is a person/group who has experience opposite to whatever claim you're making.

Comment: Come, come/come now, tell it to the marines, go tell it to Sweeney, tell it to the judge, but I don't know which one is used in BE.

Answer (score 1):

The British equivalent is...

*[Tell it to the marines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tell_It_to_the_Marines)*. Per that article it also does play a part in American English,   just not much recently.

See also [Tell it to the marines](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tell+it+to+the+marines) at the free dictionary dot com,which gives more information about both its British and American usage.

I feel like I am doing research you are fully capable of doing. I don't recollect the phrase, and all I did was type "tell it to the marines define" into  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=tell+it+to+the+Maines+define&oq=tell+it+to+the+Maines+define). Actually I even mistyped Marines as Maines and Google still knew what I meant.